# Jobs Distance Dropdown - 10 Miles Please

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs

This may be the request of a very spoiled person, but I routinely rule out jobs that are not within biking distance of where I live. That is 10 miles. (I know a person can ride a lot further than that, but practically speaking, for me, 10 miles is my limit for commuting.)

Can we please add a 10 mile option to the Jobs search distance dropdown?

Comment: Or make it a textbox variable for those who want even less or even more?

Comment: oh! good point @JonH! turns out one can hack the URL by modifying the "range" value manually. _eg_:
http://stackoverflow.com/jobs?location=60608&range=5&distanceUnits=Miles

Comment: Nice you got it!

Comment: Where do you live where you're fortunate enough for this to be an option?!?!

Comment: @Adam I'd say any larger city qualifies...

Comment: @AdamRackis one could say I am fortunate, which is true, but I also made a choice to live in Chicago. I guess I was fortunate to be able to make that choice. :)

Comment: What about "20 miles with office showers" :p

Answer (score 16):

We actually can't because of the way our geo code works. We measure the miles out from the center of the zip code, not the outer borders. Even with the URL hack, it's probably not working as well as you think it is.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. I can see how that could come about given that you'd have no idea which border of the zip code is relevant.  But the result is even more bias against finer granularity for those in densely populated areas right?

Comment: 20 miles from NYC could be a 2 hour commute, but zip codes are quite small.

Comment: I don't think this would be a problem in the UK? Most, if not all of our postcodes ("zipcodes") are just single roads, and if the roads are long then they're split into multiple codes. Real estate websites here use postcode matching to the quarter-mile, but they're surely just using the same method.