# Show distance at all times in jobs search

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs

The distance drop down selection needs some work.  If you enter a city, region, or even a postal code the distance selection is not displayed until after you have focused out of the field completely.  If you for instance, search for a job in a city I would like to work in such as Auburn Hills, MI then until I pointer click off of this box the distance drop down does not show up.

Also distance drop down only has three items: 20, 50 and 100.  We should really have at least one more selection for "Directly In" that is only in a certain city or postal code.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are two issues here.

First, the distance dropdown does not appear when you expect.  We agree that this is an issue.  Our designers are looking at redoing the search area anyway, at which time this issue should be addressed.

Second, the distance dropdown lacks a "directly in" option, or at least a more narrow option than 20 miles.  We [declined a similar feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312585/239394), and the same reasoning still applies.  We could theoretically allow exact-match on zip codes, but that's not as straightforward as it sounds, and we're not sure the user benefit is worth the cost and complexity.

So, I'm tagging as [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) because we know we need to fix the dropdown issue, but I don't have confirmation on when that will happen.

Comment: That entire search page is a confusing mess. I am glad it is being redesigned. However, your job search is really quite useless to people like myself and (possibly) JonH unless you can improve the accuracy of your search. Using the excuse that "our code doesn't allow it", is not a reason. It's software. Soft. Change it. Or don't. No sweat off our backs, we'll just find work using something that isn't so fundamentally limiting.

Comment: Ack, completely forgot to give you an example! Check out LinkedIn for an example of a search that uses an exact location correctly. Under a Location menu, they allow you to specify an exact city and state combination, and choose a distance of "Exact Location". Once done, every job opening in the search results will only be in that exact city.